# PLSQL loop for checking data availability in table

Tags: loops, plsql

There should be script that checks count(*) in one table and if count(*) is NULL then Exit, else sleep for some time and then proceed again with checking table while count(*) is NULL. My efforts were in vain:

```
declare

    v_cnt pls_integer;

begin

    while v_cnt >0 
    loop

        select count(*) into v_cnt from TestTable;

        if v_cnt is Null
        then
            exit;
        else 
            dbms_lock.sleep(6);
            dbms_output.put_line('Count is greater then Null. Current values: ' || v_cnt);

    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('TestTable does not have any data');

end;
```

Comment: missing `end if;` in the paste?

Comment: Hi, yes you're right. Apologize for such omission, i was in rush...

Comment: Do you really need to know the actual count of records, or do you just need to know if there is *at least one* record? If you really need to know the exact count of records, you may want to make sure there is at least one index on a column with a NOT NULL constraint, so that it can avoid a full table scan each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count always returns a number, not null.  Change the if to  zero instead of null and it should work. And I changed your logic around so it does not kick off if there are zero records.  Unless you are deleting records from the table I have assumed that not having any records will only happen once.  If you are deleting records and table could have zero records many times then kick this procedure off with a job that runs as often as you like and remove the while loop.

```
declare
v_cnt pls_integer;
begin
select count(*) into v_cnt from TestTable;
if v_cnt > 0 then
   while v_cnt > 0 
   loop
      select count(*) into v_cnt from TestTable;
      dbms_lock.sleep(6);
      dbms_output.put_line('Count is greater than zero . Current values: ' || v_cnt);
   end loop;

else
   dbms_output.put_line('TestTable does not have any data');

 end if;
end;
```

Comment: You're missing something here - after the count, your code will sleep and then say "count is greater than zero" even if the last count was zero.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp It only enters the while loop if the count is greater than zero as determined by the if statement. You are correct that this won't work if records are deleted after the process is started but I address that in the answer

Comment: You don't check the result of the second query until *after* the sleep + message.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I'll run it when I get to work and correct as necessary

Comment: Ok....... but you realise that your code *will run without problem* in 99.99999999999% of cases?

Comment: @kevinsky, thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, it does not work as 'exit' is allowed to work only within <loop> (illegal EXIT/CONTINUE statement; it must appear inside a loop)

Comment: @AlexPes Sorry, changed the loop so a break in the control structure was not needed